# Read embedded objects of excel in node.js

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I am using exceljs to read excel file in node.js. 
I am able to read text data with this module, but how to read embedded objects from excel file in node.js?

Thanks in advvance.

Answer (score 0):

For reading textual data from excel using node.js, You can use the following code,

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');

var wb = new Excel.Workbook();
var path = require('path');
var filePath = path.resolve(__dirname,'sample.xlsx');

wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(function(){

    var sh = wb.getWorksheet("Sheet1");

    sh.getRow(1).getCell(2).value = 32;
    wb.xlsx.writeFile("sample2.xlsx");
    console.log("Row-3 | Cell-2 - "+sh.getRow(3).getCell(2).value);

    console.log(sh.rowCount);
    //Get all the rows data [1st and 2nd column]
    for (i = 1; i <= sh.rowCount; i++) {
        console.log(sh.getRow(i).getCell(1).value);
        console.log(sh.getRow(i).getCell(2).value);
    }
});
```

I don't know how to read embedded objects using exceljs.